# JOIN error in Symfony 2.1 with two entities managers

Tags: join, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have a DB with a lot of data and I want to build a simple query in DQL with a JOIN, but I have a "has no association named" error. 
I have 2 tables in one DB, "main" and "users_main" and one table in the other DB "

This is my code:

**AdsMain.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vt\KohanaBundle\Entity\AdsUsersMain")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

**AdsMainRepository.php**

```
class AdsMainRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findPremiumsCallCenter() {

        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $consulta = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT  a.title , u.fullname
                    FROM
                        KohanaBundle:Main AS a
                            JOIN 
                        a.user AS u'
        );

        $consulta->setMaxResults(20);
        $lista = $consulta->getResult();
        return $lista;
    }
}
```

**AdsUsersMain**

```
class AdsUsersMain{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

## Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: vt #default connection
            connections:
            vt:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                        host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                        dbname:   %database_name_vt%
                user:     %database_user_vt%
                password: %database_password_vt%
                charset:  UTF8
            kohana:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                    port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name_kohana%
                user:     %database_user_kohana%
                    password: %database_password_kohana%
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        #auto_mapping: true

        default_entity_manager: vt   
        entity_managers:
        vt:
            connection: vt
            mappings:
                VentaBundle : ~
                UsuarioBundle : ~                    
        kohana:
            connection: kohana
            mappings:
                KohanaBundle : ~
```

When I call the function findPremiumsCallCenter() I have this error:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 161 near 'AS u
': Error: Class Vt\KohanaBundle\Entity\AdsMain has no association named user
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Your mapping is not correct.